# createReactionCollector only collecting bot reactions

Tags: discord.js

First time I use `createReactionCollector`.
It doesn't work, when I react the `collector` gets nothing.
But when I make the bot react, I get that reaction but, not mine.

```js
const collector = startMessage.createReactionCollector(x => {
    return true
}, { time: 5000 })

collector.on('collect', (r, collector) => {
    console.log("collected");
})

collector.on('end', r => {
    console.log(r)
})
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you're not using a valid filter, you need to pass the `reaction` and `user` parameters into the filter and use them like so:

> `const filter = (reaction, user) => reaction.emoji.name === '' && user.id === 'someID';`

Then add the filter to the collector like so:

> `const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, { time: 15000 });`

These are from the example of [`createReactionCollector()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=createReactionCollector) on the docs